# Converting data type on SQL Server View Creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm fairly new to SQL, and I'm having some problems converting a data type of Guid to String when creating my View. After having a look into the issue I'm not sure why the following statement is throwing the error:

```
Create View or Function failed because no column name was specified for column 2.
```

Statement:

```
CREATE VIEW CustomerContactView
AS
SELECT [Id]
  ,CAST([Guid] AS NVARCHAR(100)) 
  ,[ContactGuid]
  ,[MethodId]
  ,[Details]
  ,[OutcomeId]
  ,[ActionRequired]
  ,[IsValid]
FROM [Main].[dbo].[Customer_ContactLog]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me that people keep posting questions where they say "I don't understand this error", when the error clearly states EXACTLY what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to give a new name for that column that will be used when selecting from the view:

```
CREATE VIEW CustomerContactView
AS
SELECT [Id]
  ,CAST([Guid] AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS Guid
  ,[ContactGuid]
  ,[MethodId]
  ,[Details]
  ,[OutcomeId]
  ,[ActionRequired]
  ,[IsValid]
FROM [Main].[dbo].[Customer_ContactLog]
```

This is because the value in that column is calculated dynamically and is not related to the value in table. A computed column is a virtual column that is not physically stored in the table therefore the DBMS cannot use the original column name from a table.

Answer (score 1):

In a view, when you apply a function or otherwise manipulate a column, concatenate multiple columns, anything like that, you need to give that column an alias:
`CAST([Guid] AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS <some clever alias goes here>`.

Answer (score 1):

It's as exactly as the error says: you're not specifying a column name for the second column in your view. If you run that `SELECT` as-is, you'll see the following for column names:

ID     (No column name)     ContactGuid... etc.

Change it to this:

```
CREATE VIEW CustomerContactView
AS
SELECT [Id]
    ,CAST([Guid] AS NVARCHAR(100)) [Guid]
    ,[ContactGuid]
    ,[MethodId]
    ,[Details]
    ,[OutcomeId]
    ,[ActionRequired]
    ,[IsValid]
FROM [Main].[dbo].[Customer_ContactLog]
```